NextJS re-rendering initial items after navigating routes with infinite scrolling
I am trying to implement infinite scrolling in NextJS 14 with pagination handled on my Laravel backend that keeps loaded items between routes.
When I select an item in the list of the initial paginated items, it renders item details as expected, but when I load more items and select an item down the list, it loads details for a split second and return to the list with initial items only.
I load more items calling a server action from MapClient that get triggered by ShopList. I have read NextJS documention on routing and implemented item selection in MapClient:
// Handle shop selection
const handleShopDetails = useCallback((shopId: number | null) => {
    if (shopId === null) {
        setSelectedShop(null);
        router.push('/shops', { scroll: false });
    } else {
        const shop = allShops.find(shop => shop.Shop_ID === shopId);
        if (shop) {
            setSelectedShop(shop);
            const slug = shop.Name.trim().toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '-').replace(/[^\w\-]+/g, '');
            router.push(`/shops/${shop.Shop_ID}/${slug}`, { scroll: false });
        }
    }
}, [allShops, router, setSelectedShop]);

and update state from MapContext in MapClient:
const MapContent: React.FC<MapClientProps> = ({ paginateData, initialShops }) => {
    const {
        filteredShops,
        selectedShop,
        allShops,
        currentPage,
        setFilteredShops,
        setSelectedShop,
        setAllShops,
        setCurrentPage,
    } = useMapContext();

    // [...] more code

    // Shop Selection from URL
    useEffect(() => {
        const shopId = params.id;
        if (shopId && typeof shopId === 'string') {
            const shop = allShops.find(shop => shop.Shop_ID === parseInt(shopId));
            if (shop) {
                setSelectedShop(shop);
            }
        }
    }, [params, allShops, setSelectedShop]);

Both of my pages in "/shops" and "/shops/[id]/[slug]" render MapClient, where I pass initial fetched Shops. I guess this is where issue might be:
// /shops/[id]/[slug]/page.tsx
import { Metadata } from 'next';
import { MapClient } from '@/components/Map/MapClient'
import { Shop } from '@/lib/types';
import { getInitialShops } from '@/lib/api/sharedFetch';

// Only this changes between page.tsx.
export const metadata: Metadata = {
    title: "LociShop - Shop Details",
};

export default async function ShopDetailsPage() {
    const paginateResponse = await getInitialShops();
    const shops: Shop[] = paginateResponse !== null ? paginateResponse.data : [];

    return <MapClient paginateData={paginateResponse} initialShops={shops} />
}

What would be the best approach to solve this? Use an equivalent of shallow routing to prevent refresh between routes, change logic for the fetch call to handle pagination page on the server rather than client, or something else?
My directory structure is as follows if that may help:
├── actions
│   └── shops.ts ()
├── components (all client components)
│   └── Map
│       ├── GoogleMap.tsx
│       ├── Map.tsx
│       ├── MapClient.tsx
│       ├── SearchBar.tsx
│       ├── ShopDetails.tsx
│       └── ShopList.tsx
├── context
│   └── MapContext.tsx
├── lib
│   ├── api
│   │   ├── sharedFetch.ts (getShops from shops.ts cached)
│   │   └── shops.ts
└── shops
    ├── [id]
    │   └── [slug]
    │       └── page.tsx (server component)
    ├── layout.tsx (server component)
    └── page.tsx (server component)

